# Insert a new column into the Foreign Key table when a particular column in the primary key table is Update (Using Triggers)

Tags: triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

Being new to Triggers, I need some information to `INSERT` a new column into the Foreign Key table with the values from the Primary Key table, when an `UPDATE` is made in the primary key table (Only a particular column when it is updated).

I am working on a .NET project with SQL Server 2005.

Thank for the help.

Comment: I have been trying to find the information regarding triggers but to no avial...

Comment: The maximum number of [columns per table is 1024](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.90).aspx) - are you sure you don't intend inserting a new Row in the parent table?

Comment: Yes my bad, I do intend on inserting a new row @StuartLC.

Comment: I began an answer making this assumption, below, although it updates a column on the PK table, rather than inserting a new one - hopefully it helps in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather non-specific, but here's an example of using a trigger to keep a parent table's (`Table1`) count of rows in an associated child table (`Table2`) up to date.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tTable2 ON Table2 FOR INSERT, DELETE
AS BEGIN
  WITH cte AS  
  (
    SELECT T1ID 
       FROM INSERTED

    UNION

    SELECT T1ID 
       FROM DELETED
  )
  UPDATE t1
     SET t1.CountOfT2s = x.t2Count
     FROM
       Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN
       (
          SELECT cte.T1ID, COUNT(t2.T2ID) AS t2Count
          FROM cte
          LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
            ON t2.T1ID = cte.T1ID
          GROUP BY cte.T1ID
       ) x
      ON t1.T1ID = x.T1ID;    
    END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24a94/1)